# Save and reopen Spaces configuration in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-spaces

Let's say that I am working using several spaces. In one of them I have 20 applications opened with their respective files. My computer crashes and I have to open everything again.
Instead I want to save this configuration so I can later reopen this configuration, and immediately open all these 20 applications with those files, and even better, reopen them in the same positions and sizes they had before.

I wonder if it could be done using AppleScript or something like that. If you give me hints, I can dig deeper and learn it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/), but I think it's not designed for this task.

---

Alternatively, with AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using control down # press control-right to navigate to space 2 if you're on 1

tell application "Safari"
    activate # bring to foreground, open window
    set bounds of window 1 to {50, 50, 500, 500} # window position and size
end tell
```

Using this code, you can navigate around your spaces, open applications and resize their windows. I think some applications that aren't AppleScriptable might not work though.